# Composite key - one a foreign key, the other auto-incrementing

Tags: mysql, composite

I'm having trouble creating a table in MySQL. Essentially, I need a composite key using "client_id" and "problem_id". In the table "clients", "client_id" is the primary key so I want to keep this relationship, and "problem_id" needs to be auto incrementing.

```
CREATE TABLE problems (
client_id BIGINT(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES clients(client_id),
problem_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
status CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
start_date VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
end_date VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (client_id, problem_id)
);
```

MySQL won't accept this, but it seems logical to me. How can I achieve such a table?

Comment: Are you obliged to use InnoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

- InnoDB requires that the auto_increment column be the first column in your primary key.
- InnoDB does not support column-level `REFERENCES` syntax, it only supports table-level `FOREIGN KEY` constraint syntax.

This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE problems (
 client_id BIGINT(10) NOT NULL,
 problem_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 status CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
 description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 start_date VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 end_date VARCHAR(10),
 PRIMARY KEY (problem_id, client_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES clients(client_id)
);
```

However, this means that your clustered index (the primary key) is going to benefit lookups 
by problem_id, but not lookups by client_id.

Comment: Yes - the error message seems somewhat misleading in this respect ! "ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

Answer (score 1):

According to the [AUTO INCREMENT docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), you can only use an auto-increment column in a composite key if you're using the MyISAM or BDB engines:

> > For MyISAM and BDB tables you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index.

If you're using InnoDB, this presumably isn't allowed. I'd suggest using only the `problem_id` as the primary key - it's unique on its own and I don't see any benefit in combining it with the `client_id`.

Comment: A single client can have many problems, so I need to identify the problems also

Comment: You should still be OK with the only `problem_id` as the primary key. Just create a "regular" index on the `client_id` column (Gilbert Le Blanc's answer suggests this as well) and any query for problems by client should be super-fast.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have to make problem_id the primary (clustering) key, and create another index on client_id.  MySQL includes a reference to the primary key as a part of other indexes.

```
CREATE TABLE problem (
    problem_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    client_id BIGINT(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES clients(client_id),
    status CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    start_date DATE NOT NULL,
    end_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (problem_id)
    INDEX problem_ndx1 (client_id)
);
```

Comment: The problem_id must still be able to be used in WHERE clauses and so on, and a client_id is not enough to uniquely identify the rows. Will that still work?

Comment: @Amoeba: A WHERE clause with the client_id, problem_id (in that order) will use the problem_ndx1 index I defined to return one row.  A WHERE clause with just the client_id will return all the problem rows.  If the order is important, add start_date descending to the problem_ndx1 index.

Comment: I haven't used indexes before. So a single problem row is still uniquely identifiable by the combination of problem_id and client_id?

Comment: @Amoeba: Yes.  A single problem row is uniquely identifiable by the combination of client_id and problem_id.